# How to show image in Scrollable GridLayout in Kivy

Tags: android, python, image, kivy

I have `Scrollable Grid Layout` in Kivy and I am trying to add Image in that Scrolling view as below.I am not able to see it and I am also trying to make that image change it's size as per dynamically as per screen resolution.

```html
Screen:
   name:"easy_1_1"
   canvas.before:
    Color: 
     rgba:0.2,0.3,0.4,1
    Rectangle:
     size:self.size
   BoxLayout:
    orientation:"vertical"
    padding:20
    spacing:10
    
  
     
    ScrollView:
     GridLayout:
      size_hint: (1, None)
      height: self.minimum_height
      id: layout_content
      cols: 1
      spacing:10
      padding:10
      rows:3
      
      Label:
       text_size:self.size
       text:"[b]What is Programming ?[/b]"
       size_hint_y:None
       valign: 'top'
       font_size:"24sp"
       color:1,1,1,1
       markup:True
       height:"100sp"
       halign:"left"
       halign:'center' 
      
      
      Label:
       text_size:self.size
       text:"test"*100 
       size_hint_y:None
       valign: 'top'
       font_size:"17sp"
       color:1,1,1,1
       markup:True
       height:"660sp"
       halign:"left"
       halign:'center' 
       
              #PRoblem is here can not see the image

      Image:
       source:"aa.png"
       
       
       
     
      
      
    Button:
     text:"Back"
     pos_hint_x:None
     size_hint_y:None
     height:"30dp"
     background_normal: 'blue_with_finger.png'
     background_down: 'bb1.png'
     on_release:sm.current="easy_1"
```

as mention in code above I can not add image in the scroll able layout...any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling the `size_hint` (the y part at least) for your Image:
`size_hint_y: None`
You'll probably need to define a size , also.

`size_hint` doesn't seem to work (even the default 1, 1) but, since I haven't worked with a `GridLayout`, this might be the normal behavior.